# Weblogic SSL Handshake failure

Tags: ssl, weblogic, ssl-certificate

I'm getting the blow exception while doing WS call .
Server : WL 9.2
Java : 1.5

```
Throws: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3s://dez221:7054: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
            javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received.; No available router to destination]
```

Then I started the WL with SSL debug on and got :

```
<Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <write ALERT, offset = 0, length = 2>
    <Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <close(): 23074502>
    <Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <close(): 23074502>
    <Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <SSLIOContextTable.removeContext(ctx): 25553895>
    <Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <Filtering JSSE SSLSocket>
    <Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <SSLIOContextTable.addContext(ctx): 17949172>
    <Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <SSLSocket will  be Muxing>
    <Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <write SSL_20_RECORD>
    <Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <isMuxerActivated: false>
    <Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <15808500 SSL3/TLS MAC>
    <Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <15808500 received HANDSHAKE>
    <Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <HANDSHAKEMESSAGE: ServerHello>
    <Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <HANDSHAKEMESSAGE: Certificate>
    <Apr 29, 2015 2:42:00 PM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <000000> <NEW ALERT with Severity: FATAL, Type: 42
    java.lang.Exception: New alert stack
            at com.certicom.tls.record.alert.Alert.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.handleHandshakeMessages(Unknown Source)
```

Can't find the reason for this.
Please advice.

Comment: Have you run `keytool -v -list -keystore` on the cert you're using? Are you using wildcards in the cert? What is your ssl config? https://community.oracle.com/thread/1059388 http://oraclefuzion.blogspot.com/2014/07/fatal-alert-badcertificate-corrupt-or.html

Comment: Acutlly we are using the DemoIdentity\DemoTrust  .  Now I import the certificate of the server we are calling too , and getting :   The loading of the truste
d certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The issue was that the server we were calling to (WebLogic 12\Java 8) generated DemoIdentity.jks which contain certificate with SHA256WITHRSA algorithm which can't be read by the calling server (WebLogic 9.2 \Java 1.5).

I generated new DemoIdentity.jks with WL9.2 CertGen which generating the certificate with MD5WITHRSA algorithm, I placed it in the WebLogic12\lib folder and then we were able to get successful calls to the Weblogic 12 server.